# James Bond Linked List from C for Dummies

Tags: c, compilation, initialization, string-concatenation, string-literals

I am trying this code out of C for Dummies, but for some reason, it doesn't give any output, and I'm not sure why because it's the same as in the book. Can anyone see why this is happening?

```
int main(void){
    struct jb{
        char actor[25];
        struct jb *next;
    };

    char *bonds[RECORDS]= {
        "Sean Connery"
        "David Niven"
        "George Lazenby"
        "Roger Moore"
        "Timothy Dolton"
        "Pierce Brosnan"
    };

    struct jb *first_item;
    struct jb *current_item;
    struct jb *new_item;
    int index = 0;

    // create first structure in the list
    first_item = (struct jb *)malloc(sizeof(struct jb));
    current_item = first_item;

    //fill in the structure - while loop iteerrates across each item in the list
    while(1){
        strcpy(current_item->actor,bonds[index]);

        index++;
        if(index < RECORDS){
            new_item = (struct jb *)malloc(sizeof(struct jb));
            current_item->next = new_item;
            current_item = new_item;
        } else {
            current_item->next = NULL;
            break;

        }
    }

    //display the results
    current_item = first_item;  //start over
    index = 1;

    while(current_item){
        printf("Structure %d: ",index++);
        printf("%s \n",current_item->actor);
        current_item = current_item->next;
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Expected output:

```
Structure 1: Sean Connery
Structure 2: David Niven
Structure 3: George Lazenby
Structure 4: Roger Moore
Structure 5: Timothy Dolton
Structure 6: Pierce Brosnan
```

Comment: Your `bonds` array has one long string and five implicit `NULL` entries. You probably want commas after each Bond actor's name. The way it is, all names are concatenated to form one long string. (In C, `"Au" "ric"` is the same as `"Auric"`.)

Answer (score 0):

The reason of the problem is this declaration of an array

```
char *bonds[RECORDS]= {
    "Sean Connery"
    "David Niven"
    "George Lazenby"
    "Roger Moore"
    "Timothy Dolton"
    "Pierce Brosnan"
};
```

You forgot to separate initializers by commas.

```
char *bonds[RECORDS]= {
    "Sean Connery",
    "David Niven",
    "George Lazenby",
    "Roger Moore",
    "Timothy Dolton",
    "Pierce Brosnan"
};
```

As a result you have in fact

```
char *bonds[RECORDS]= {
    "Sean ConneryDavid NivenGeorge LazenbyRoger MooreTimothy DoltonPierce Brosnan"
};
```

due to concatenation of adjacent string literals.

That is only the first element of the array is explicitly initialized by an initializer. All other elements by default are initialized as null pointers.

And you may not use a null pointer as an argument of the function `strcpy`. Otherwise such a call with a null pointer as an argument invokes undefined behavior.

From the C Standard (5.1.1.2 Translation phases)

> 1 The precedence among the syntax rules of translation is specified by
> the following phases
>
> ...
>
> 6. Adjacent string literal tokens are concatenated.

Comment: Thank you so much for this response; this helps me because I would have never spotted that!